# Retrieve key values from BSON document using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm working with MongoDB using Ruby.

I am able to query a document by doing something like this:

```
client[:inventory].find({"owner": identity}, projection: {"_id": 0, "group": 1}).each do |doc| 
  #Finds and returns a BSON document matching the query.
  puts doc.to_s
end
```

However this gives the following key/value pair in String representation:

```
{"name" => "john"}
```

How would I retrieve **only** the value from the returned BSON document, removing the braces and hash rocket, in this case `john`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `doc` is a simple hash, you can call `.values` method on it, returning values of the hash. And if you're sure there is only one pair of key-value, or you need only the first one, try this:

```
- puts doc.to_s
+ puts doc.values.first
```